# De qual maneira poderia esconder demais números de paginação

Tags: javascript

Tenho o *código fonte* já escrito. Confira logo abaixo:

```js
var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZ"

var link = [];

for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
{
var letra = str.charCodeAt(i) - 64;
link[i] = "<a href='base/dados/"+ letra +".html' target='resultado'>" + (i+1) + "</a>";  
}

document.getElementById("listagem").innerHTML = link.join("&nbsp;");

window.onload = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].className="hover"

var pag = document.getElementsByTagName('a')

var contar = 0; 

function troca(i) {
if (i == 'e') {
if (contar > 0) {
  pag[contar].className = ""
  contar--;
  pag[contar].className += "hover";
 }
 } else {
 if (contar < pag.length - 1) {
  pag[contar].className = ""
  contar++;
  pag[contar].className += "hover";
 }
 }
 }
```

```css
 a { 

 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 1px 4px 1px 4px; 
 color: black; 

 }

 a.hover { 

 color:red; 
     font-weight: bolder;
     background-color: red;
     color: white;

 }

 a:hover { 

 color:red; 
     font-weight: bolder;
     background-color: red;
     color: white;

 }

.seta {

   cursor: pointer;

}
```

```html
<div id="resultado"></div>

<button onclick="troca('e')" id="menos" class="seta">&#171</button>

<span id="listagem"></span>

<button onclick="troca('d')" id="mais" class="seta">&#187</button>
```

Mas surgiu a necessidade de mostrar só os *quatro* primeiros números de paginação, deixando-o assim:

***< 1 2 3 4 >***

O restante fica escondido. Então quando for clicar em "*próximo*/*anterior*" deverá ir ***sumindo e mostrando*** os novos elementos. Veja:

***< 2 3 4 5 >***

***< 3 4 5 6 >***

***< 4 5 6 7 >***

assim por diante ...

> Em outras palavras seria uma "*roleta*". Isso mesmo em forma dum "*carrossel*"

Creio que seria algo do tipo `incrementar-e-decrementar` em *javascript*

Mas como implementar isso ao *código fonte*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz as devidas adaptações na tua lógica, porem é possivel implementar tudo isso de uma forma melhor. Se você quer que a paginação seja alterada conforme opção selecionada, você deve recria-la dinamicamente.

```js
var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZ"

var link = [];
var contar = 0;

function makePagination() {

    link = [];

    for (var i = contar > 2 ? contar - 2 : 0; i < contar + (contar < 2 || contar == str.length ? 4 - contar : 2) && i < str.length; i++) {
        var letra = str.charCodeAt(i) - 64;

        if (i == contar) {
            link[i] = "<a href='base/dados/" + letra + ".html' target='resultado' class='hover'>" + (i + 1) + "</a>";
        } else {
            link[i] = "<a href='base/dados/" + letra + ".html' target='resultado' class=''>" + (i + 1) + "</a>";
        }

    }

    document.getElementById("listagem").innerHTML = link.join('');

}



makePagination();



function troca(i) {


    if (i == 'e') {
        if (contar > 0) {
            contar--;
        }
    } else {
        if (contar < link.length - 1) {
            contar++;
        }
    }
    makePagination();
}
```

```css
a { 

 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 1px 4px 1px 4px; 
 color: black; 

 }

 a.hover { 

 color:red; 
     font-weight: bolder;
     background-color: red;
     color: white;

 }

 a:hover { 

 color:red; 
     font-weight: bolder;
     background-color: red;
     color: white;

 }

.seta {

   cursor: pointer;

}
```

```html
<div id="resultado"></div>

<button onclick="troca('e')" id="menos" class="seta">&#171</button>

<span id="listagem"></span>

<button onclick="troca('d')" id="mais" class="seta">&#187</button>
```

Também recomendo utilizar um número ímpar de páginas, para que a opção selecionada possa ficar no centro, melhorando o aspecto.

Comment: Realmente ficou muito bom, agradeço seu esforço em me ajudar.